# operator '*' cannot be applied for operands of type 'Vector3' and 'Quaternion'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Error:
operator '*' cannot be applied for operands of type 'Vector3' and 'Quaternion'

> rb.MoveRotation(rb.position *Quaternion.Euler (rotation));

I copied this code out of youtube (it worked properly there ..it was the old version of visual studio I guess)

rotation is Vector3 its unable to convert into Quaternion what should i do?

Here is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
public class PlayerMotor : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector3 velocity =Vector3.zero;
    private Vector3 rotation = Vector3.zero;

    private Rigidbody rb;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }
    // Get movement from PlayerController Script
    public void Move (Vector3 _velocity)
    {
        velocity = _velocity;
    }
    // Get Rotation from PlayerController Script
    public void Rotate (Vector3 _rotation)
    {
        rotation = _rotation;
    }
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        PerformMovement();
        PerformRotation();
    }
    // Actually performing the rotation
    void PerformMovement()
    {
        if(velocity!=Vector3.zero)
        {
            rb.MovePosition(rb.position + velocity * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        }  
    }
    // Actually performing the rotation
    void PerformRotation()
    {
        rb.MoveRotation(rb.position *Quaternion.Euler (rotation));
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to actually multiply your position with the movement Quaternion. I would try to replace the ```rb.position *Quaternion.Euler(rotation)``` with ```Quaternion.Euler(rotation)```and see if you get the expected result.

Comment: Are you maybe trying to place an object in a position that is a certain angle from another object?

Answer (score 3):

See [`Quaternion` operator `*`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion-operator_multiply.html)

It can only be used in the order `Quaternion * Vector3` which means you rotate the given vector

or on two `Quaternion` for using the first rotation an on top of it add the second one (order matters!)

---

In your case the issue is **not** that it is `unable to convert into Quaternion` but rather that `rb.position` is a `Vector3`.

Most probably you do not want to use the `rb.position` but rather `rb.rotation` in

```
void PerformRotation()
{
    rb.MoveRotation(rb.rotation * Quaternion.Euler (rotation));
}
```

Comment: rb. rotation * Quaternion worked perfectly for me